# Label figures in col-major order

Tags: subfloats

Use the following commands, I can generate a 2x3 table figures:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}} &
\subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}} &
\subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{7}} \\
\subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}} &
\subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{9}} &
\subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{8}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here goes the caption.}
\label{fig6}
\end{figure}
```

I will get:

[image]

The figures are labeled in row-major order. **My question is that how can I label them in col-major order in order to get something like the following figure?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If case you want something ordered by columns, a first approach could be put it in a `multicols` environment:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent
\subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{8}}\par 
\subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{9}}\newpage 
\subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{7}}\par 
\subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{8}}\newpage
\subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{9}}\par
\subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{8}}
\end{multicols}
\caption{Here goes the caption.}
\label{fig6}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is use of three `tabular` environment with one column each.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
\subfloat[configuration 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{8}} \\
\subfloat[configuration 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{9}}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\subfloat[configuration 3]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{7}} \\
\subfloat[configuration 4]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{8}} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\subfloat[configuration 5]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{9}} \\
\subfloat[configuration 6]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{8}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here goes the caption.}
\label{fig6}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```